# Asymptotic behavior of $x_k = \sin (x_{k-1})$

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

Given the recurrence, $x_k = \sin (x_{k-1})$ where $x_1 \neq 0$, I know that $x_k \rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$. I am looking for a simple $f(k)$ such that $|x_k| = \Theta(f(k))$. Any ideas on where to start?

Comment: Hint: Show that $$\frac1{x_k^2}-\frac1{x_{k-1}^2}\to\frac13$$ hence $$x_k\sim\mathrm{sign}(x_1)\cdot\sqrt{3}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$$ The only needed tool is the expansion $$\sin t=t-\frac{t^3}6+o(t^3)$$ when $t\to0$.

Comment: @Did awesome, I get it thanks :). If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Better option: you turn these indications into a full answer (replacing my idiotic $\sqrt{n}$ by $\sqrt{k}$, to begin with...) and you post it below.

Comment: @Did Sure, will do that. Just a question, the missing piece for me was the first line in your comment. How did you "guess" that that was the right starting point?

Comment: Once one knows that $x_k\to0$ and that $$x_{k+1}-x_k\sim -cx_k^{1+a}$$ (say, with $c$, $x_1$ and $a$ positive), one can have the idea of considering the differential equation $$x'(t)=-cx(t)^{1+a}$$ with $x(0)$ positive, solved by $$x(t)^{-a}=x(0)^{-a}+act$$ Then the change of variable $$z(t)=x(t)^{-a}$$ is natural, and suggests the change of variable $$z_k=x_k^{-a}$$ In your case, $a=2$...

Comment: @Did got it! Thanks!